# Virtualbox SSH from Windows 7 (host) to CentOS (guest)

Tags: windows-7, ssh, virtualbox, centos, firewall

My network adapter is set to "Bridged Adapter". My CentOS (guest) IP is `192.168.0.4` and I am able to view Apache web server (port 80) from Windows 7 (host) but I am unable to SSH (port 22). I get "connection refused" from putty.

Here's a screenshot of my iptables in CentOS:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing the Apache HTTP Server welcome page using *localhost* and not the IP address, then it is possible that `dhcpcd` is not running. Have you verified that `sshd` is running?

Comment: Wow I think I better go to sleep `sshd` was simply not running. LOL.

Comment: Haha, it happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you can connect to the CentOS VB

> ping 192.168.0.4

- Make sure sshd is running, the "connection refused message" usually means that sshd is not running.

> ```
> /etc/init.d/sshd restart
> ```

- Your firewall configuration appears to be ok, but just in case disable it for testing.

> ```
> /etc/init.d/iptables stop
> ```

- Also check your configuration in /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny, at least must have a line like:

> sshd : 192.168.0.  : allow